# In Spring Java, when a client submits a POST request to save an object, how to disallow the binding to the database generated id field?

Tags: java, spring, binding

I have an HTML form named CreateApplicationType.html. This is where someone can create a new ApplicationType object to be processed by the server and stored in the database.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Create Application Type</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Create Application Type</h2>
<table>
    <form th:action="@{/applicationType/save}" method="post" th:object="${applicationType}" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
        <tr>
            <td><label>Application Type: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{applicationType}" placeholder="Application Type"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Application Type Abbreviation: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{applicationTypeAbbreviation}" placeholder="Application Type Abbreviation"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Application Type Description: </label></td>
            <td><input type="text" th:field="*{applicationTypeDescription}" placeholder="Application Type Description"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>Application Type is Public?</label></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" th:field="*{isPublic}" placeholder="Application Type is Public?"/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><label>TODO: Application Type Steps: </label></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><button type="submit">Submit</button></td>
        </tr>
    </form>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my ApplicationType entity class:

```
package org.foam.civ.model.application;

import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.List;

@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Entity
@Table(name="ApplicationType")
public class ApplicationType {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, unique = true)
    private String applicationType;

    @Column
    private String applicationTypeAbbreviation;

    @Column
    private String applicationTypeDescription;

    @Column
    private Boolean isPublic;

    @OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<ApplicationStep> applicationSteps;
}
```

And here is the relevant function from my ApplicationTypeController RESTController class:

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
public void saveApplicationType(@ModelAttribute ApplicationType applicationType){
    System.out.println(applicationType.toString());
    applicationTypeService.saveApplicationType(applicationType);
}
```

When I test filling out the fields and submitting, I get the following error:

```
Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.foam.civ.model.application.ApplicationType'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Cool Application Type'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CoolApplicationType"
org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'org.foam.civ.model.application.ApplicationType'; nested exception is org.springframework.core.convert.ConversionFailedException: Failed to convert from type [java.lang.String] to type [java.lang.Long] for value 'Cool Application Type'; nested exception is java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "CoolApplicationType"
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:79)
    at org.springframework.beans.TypeConverterSupport.convertIfNecessary(TypeConverterSupport.java:53)
    ...
    ...
```

The only Long in my model is the id field, which is automatically generated by the database. So Spring must be trying to map the applicationType field from the client to the id field on the ApplicationType object. That id is automatically generated by the database, so I don't want to include it as a submission field or bind a value to it on the server side.

Is there a way to tell Spring to not bind to the id field, since that is automatically generated by the database? Do I need some sort of ApplicationTypeDTO class that only includes the fields that are to be used by the client? Then I could convert that DTO to the ApplicationType object on the server side before saving?

Comment: Consider having different endpoints for creating a new resource and update of an existing resource.  In the endpoint for the new resource, the Id is not part of the  request payload.  In the endpoint for the update resource, the Id is required (or some other attribute that can uniquely identify the resource).

Comment: @AndrewS thanks, I will keep that in mind once I start working on the update functionality!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue you're facing stems from Spring trying to turn a String value into an object of type `ApplicationType`. The problem might lie in the conversion process. The error message hints that there's an effort to change a String value ('Cool Application Type') into a Long, probably related to the `id` field.

A few things you need to can check:

1. Make sure your HTML form fields match up with the fields in the ApplicationType entity. Name the form fields similar to how the entity's fields are named, like applicationType, applicationTypeAbbreviation, applicationTypeDescription, and isPublic.

   Application Type:

2. For DTOs, if you're using them to shuttle data between the form and controller, check that the DTO fields align perfectly with the form fields. Take a good look at the getters and setters in your DTO.
3. In the controller method, the @ModelAttribute annotation should accurately map the form fields to the ApplicationType object. The form fields in your HTML should mirror the fields in the ApplicationType object.
4. If the ID field gets auto-generated by the database, skip adding it to the form or the DTO. Let the database do its thing and generate the ID when you save the ApplicationType.

   @Id

   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

   private Long id;

Remember, using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) is smart. It will help to separate the client's sent data from the server's entity. Create an ApplicationTypeDTO class with just the fields needed for the form. Then, on the server side, convert it into the ApplicationType entity before saving.
For example

@Data
public class ApplicationTypeDTO {

```
private String applicationType;
private String applicationTypeAbbreviation;
private String applicationTypeDescription;
private Boolean isPublic;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, I created a DTO and updated my other classes (controller, template, service). I used ModelMapper to map between the DTO and model classes. After doing that, it works.

Comment: This answer looks AI generated...